# How to stop ax getting stuck in log when splitting wood?

Tags: felling

As a noob wood cutter I've watched a bunch of YouTube videos, but the thing I never see is the person getting their ax stuck in the log.

I know you can turn the log upside down to free the ax but why am I having this issue (very often) and how can I avoid it?

I wondered, could my ax be *too* sharp so it sinks in too deep? I don't mind lots of hits needed to split the log, but having to keep freeing it is a real pain.

Comment: ~ same problem... I think maybe it just takes practice?

Answer (score 3):

Your axe blade might be ground at the wrong angle for splitting. Ideally, you need two axes, with blade of the "splitting" one ground to a thicker angle, so it doesn't penetrate the wood as far as a thinner blade.

For a big log, don't aim at the middle, but towards the edge nearest to you (that is safer than aiming at the edge furthest away, because of where the split pieces of wood and the axe blade are likely to end up). The wood in the middle is the strongest part of the tree, so aim at the weaker part instead.

Another "trick" is not to strike the wood exactly in the direction of the grain, but at a slight angle, so the axe blade forces the wood apart as it tries to cut into it.

All these tips work on the same basic principle - you are not trying to *cut through* the wood (which will fail when your axe gets stuck and comes to a stop, if you can't cut all the way through with a single stroke) but to make the wood *break* into two pieces along the grain.

Note, it's impossible to have an axe that is "too sharp." As with other hand-held cutting tools, sharper means safer, not more dangerous, because the axe is less likely to bounce off the wood and hit your legs or feet, instead of biting into the wood safely.

Comment: I never split wood with an axe, only with a splitting maul or a splitting wedge hit with a sledgehammer. MUCH safer that way. Occasionally the wedge or maul would get stuck in the wood, at which point I used a 3 pound hammer (struck sideways) to free them.

Comment: Wedges can be dangerous - they can jump out and fly a long way, if your aim with the sledgehammer isn't very accurate.

Comment: I think "maul" is a US term. It isn't in the Oxford (British) English Dictionary with the meaning of "a tool for splitting wood," though it does have other meanings. In Middle English it meant a hammer or a club, not something with a bladed edge. It is in the Oxford US English Dictionary.

Comment: I think you're right: it could be an American colloquialism. Sorry about any confusion. A splitting maul is essentially a sledgehammer with a tapered edge, not bladed like an axe; it's usually used for splitting wood: https://www.amleo.com/splitting-maul-large-eye-8-lb-with-36in-hickory-handle/p/11903/

Comment: A splitting ax is wider and heavier than a felling/cutting ax since as mentioned its job is not cutting. But not as blunt or heavy as a maul

Answer (score 1):

An old trick I was taught by a competition axeman was to paint/coat the blade every so often with an oily rag or an old paint brush dipped in sump oil or such. I saw old bloke out in the bush wipe his axe with a lump of fat, presumably for the same effect. A blockbuster/maul such as the Fiskars Isocore (8lbs) or a proper splitting axe such as the Fiskars x27 (4lbs) might be a better choice in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to swing harder, so it splits in one go.  Or do the reverse, and hit shallower blows but at an angle and cut a wedge out before final blows.

If the log is bigger and/or you have lots to do then it would be easier to use a chainsaw or a log splitter.  The cheap log splitters are basically a car jack with a wedge.  To split 6-10 cubic metres each year, I ended up investing in a chainsaw and a electric splitter.

It also helps to dry the log.

Answer (score 0):

If you're splitting down the tree, split up the tree. If you're splitting up the tree split down (I don't remember which way it is).

Split when the wood is frozen as it will be like splitting an ice cube.

Comment: I learned the phrase “the wood splits as the bird shits” (roughly translated) from my extended family where making wood was and still is a well-practiced craft.